# Uso de recursos al Ejecutar en Java

Tags: java, netbeans

He creado un pequeño código en NETBEANS donde imprimo los pasos de los números de la conjetura de Collatz. El tema es que cuando está ejecutando números grandes la espera es mucha y el procesador no llega ni al 10% de uso.
Quisiera saber si se puede usar más al procesador, por lo menos al 50%

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //int n = 6;
        long i = 5;//numero inicial
        long m;//numero final
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingrese un número: ");
            m = sc.nextLong();
        while(i<=m) {
            long n = i;
            long pasos=0;
            System.out.print("Con "+n+": ");//señala que numero actual
            while(n != 1) { 
        if(n % 2 == 0) // Si es par 
            n = n / 2; //dividir entre 2
        else
            n = (n * 3) + 1;//multiplicar x3 y sumar 1
        System.out.print(n+"   ");
        pasos++;//cuenta los pasos
    }
        System.out.print("\nCantidad de pasos: "+pasos+"\n");
        i++;//continua al siguiente número
        }
        
    }
```

[image: dos marionetas]

Comment: Sin ver el código es complicado saberlo. Tampoco sabemos cómo estás obteniendo ese valor de 10% de uso de CPU. La pregunta es muy vaga en detalles tal y como está expuesta, te recomiendo [edit] y ampliarla con los detalles necesarios para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: Corrección, el 10% de uso se debe a los demás programas, pero en si la ejecución del código usa solo un 0.6% casi todo el tiempo

Comment: Imprimir texto en consola es una operación bastante lenta. Si bien tu CPU seguramente sea capaz de trabajar mucho más rápido al hacer operaciones, al forzarla a ir escribiendo cosas por consola en cada iteración la estás limitando a quedarse a la espera hasta que termina la escritura (las operaciones I/O suelen ser siempre lentas :)). Por otro lado... tu código trabaja sobre un único hilo, si tienes 8 cores, el máximo de CPU que va a llegar a ocupar tu programa es un 12.5% (más o menos, vaya. La JVM y tal imagino que usarán algo, pero debería ser desdeñable).